# Display.syncExec not working inside Callable

Tags: java, concurrency, eclipse-plugin, runnable, callable

I create a `Callable` which should make a `syncExec` call. I delegate the Callable to a subclass of `RecursiveTask (ForkJoinPool)` which executes the `call` method of the `Callable`. The problem is that the code inside the `run` method is never reached. Do you know why and how to fix that?

```
public class someClass{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Callable<Object> c = new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         System.out.println("hi");
                    }

                });

                return null;
            }
        });
        ATLockTask task = new ATLockTask();
        task.setCallable(c);
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(task);
    }

}


public class ATLockTask extends RecursiveTask<Object[]>{

    Callable callable;

    @Override
    protected Object[] compute() {

        try {
            callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see a stack trace in the console?

Comment: We need to see something much closer to an [mcve] that we can actually test.

Comment: I don't know how make that example even smaller. This is the minimal complete example.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann no the printStackTrace is not reached. The call method does not get finished. It just stops at the syncExec statement.

Comment: Now, I created a full example which you can test.

Comment: Try replacing `PlatformUI...getDisplay()` with Display.getDefault()`.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't change anything. The code inside run() just doesn't get executed.

Comment: There are compile errors in your snippet. After fixing them, I can see 'hi' being printed to the console.

Answer (score 1):

`ForkJoinPool.invoke` blocks the current thread until the given task has completed. `Display.syncExec` waits until the SWT UI thread executes  `Display.readAndDispatch` so it will wait forever because `ForkJoinPool.invoke` is blocking the UI thread.

Use `ForkJoinPool.execute` to start the task without blocking and the code works.

Comment: That makes sence. But even when I use execute instead of invoke, my run method doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, the run method gets stock at this.wait() although the current thread is a ForkJoinWorker

Comment: Well you still haven't actually given us a proper [mcve] that we can test without having to guess how you are using the code. I took your current code, fixed it to compile and ran it in an Eclipse plugin and it worked properly when using `execute` and didn't run with `invoke`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579230/run-method-not-working-inside-forkjointask

Can you test that?