# Run method not working inside ForkJoinTask

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, runnable

I have a sub class of `RecursiveTask` which contains a `Runnable` object and should execute it.The problem is that the code inside the run method never gets reached although I use `ForkJoinPool.execute` in order to not block the main thread.

```
 public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("lo");
                    }

                });

            }
        };

        ATLockTask t = new ATLockTask(); 
        t.runnable = r;
        new ForkJoinPool().execute(t); 


    }
}


public class ATLockTask extends RecursiveTask<Object>{
    public Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected Object compute() {

        try {
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.catching(e);
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: Thread states before entering syncExec]

[image: Thread states after entering syncExec]

Comment: Is this really the code you are running? Because this won't work in a plain `main` method. If you are running something in an Eclipse plugin you need to tell us how you are running it in the plugin.

Comment: This code runs fine for me when run in a plugin.

Comment: I have a class `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`. In that class I overwrite the method `preWindowOpen()` in which a method of another class gets called which executes the code above. May it be the case that the main thread is always blocked while running `preWindowOpen()` ?

Comment: It isn't blocked forever but it is likely that the syncExec won't run until the application window displays.

Comment: I added two images. The first one is before execution of `syncExec`. There, the state of the `ForkJoinPoolWorker`is 'suspended`. The second image is after execution of `syncExec`. There, the state of the `ForkJoinPoolWorker`is 'stepping`.